# Getting error while making ERC721 soul bound

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, openzeppelin-contracts, foundry

I am making a soul-bound NFT using openzeppelin and foundry in solidity `^0.8.13`

And for that, I am overriding the `_beforeTokenTransfer` but on that function, I am getting an error.

> Function has override specified but does not override anything.

My Code:-

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Burnable, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;


    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256
    ) internal pure override {
        require(
            from == address(0) || to == address(0),
            "transfer not allowed"
        );
    }

}
```

I also tried the code with `override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)` but its not working as well.

I need help figuring out why I am getting this error and why the function is not accepting overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)

Fix it for you:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;


    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to,uint256 , uint256)
        internal
        pure
        override(ERC721) 
    {
        require(
            from == address(0) || to == address(0),
            "transfer not allowed"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried but isn't working.

Comment: So there are a few errors in your code. 1. ERC721Burnable is not imported. 2.Missing one argument in _beforeTokenTransfer function. 3.You are compiling with solidity ^0.8.13 but in the code you specify -08.13

Comment: I was wrong too, apparently override(ERC721)  is correct, ERC721URIStorage does not have _beforeTokenTransfer function.